# How to accept a parameter in any order in a shell script

Tags: shell

1. How can I pass a parameter in any order using a shell script? For example:

   ```
   ./my_script.sh -h hdfs_path -s s3_loc -f file_name
   ./my_script.sh -s s3_loc -h hdfs_path -f file_name
   ./my_script.sh -f file_name -h hdfs_path -s s3_loc
   ```
2. I have to pass 5 parameters, but I want to write my shell command like this:

   ```
   `-m mode_to_open_file ./myscript.sh -h hdfs_path -s s3_loc -f` file_name
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this using `getopt`. It is used to break up (parse) options in command lines for easy parsing by shell procedures, and to check for legal options.

This example you can use in your problem to solve it:

```
#!/bin/bash 

while getopts u:p: option 
do 
 case "${option}" 
 in 
 u) USER=${OPTARG};; 
 p) PASSWORD=${OPTARG};; 
 esac 
done 

echo "User:"$USER 
echo "Password:"$PASSWORD
```

Above in the code, in any order of arguments, correct parameters will be passed to the function.

Comment: Thanks very much @nileshkumar for your help

Answer (score 1):

Th usual method is just to loop over the options, processing them.  Common is something like

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    case $1 in
    -h)
        echo "got -h option with arg $2"
        shift
        shift
        ;;
    *)
        echo "some other arg: $1"
        shift
        ;;
    esac
done
```